# Segmentation Fault while accessing array of char

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

Given a list of numbers and a positive integer k,I have to reverse the elements of the list, k items at a time. If the number of elements is not a multiple of k, then the remaining items in the end should be left as is:

for eg:
input : 1,2,3,4,5;2

output : 2,1,4,3,5

I have used a very simple concept i am taking two pointers a&b at the two ends to be swapped and iterating them through the entire loop.

I am getting a segmentation fault. How should i correct it?

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void reverse(char str[],int p)
{
    int i,j,k,a,b;
    int len=strlen(str);
    printf("%d\n",len);
    a=0;
    b=p-1;
    while(1)
    {
        i=a;j=b;
        while(j>i)
        {
          k=str[i];
          str[i]=str[j];
          str[j]=k;
          i++;
          j--;
        }
        a=a+p;
        b=b+p;
        if(b>=len)
        break;  
    }
    for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
    printf("%c,",str[i]);
    if(i==len-1)
    printf("%c",str[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Wrong number of arguments\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File can't be openend:\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    char c;
    c=fgetc(fp);
    char str[100];
    memset(str,'0',100);
    int k,i;
    while(1)
    {
        k=0;
        while(c!=';')
        {
          if(c!=',')
          {
            str[k]=c;
            k++;
            c=fgetc(fp);
          }
          else
          c=fgetc(fp);
        }
        str[k]='\0';
        c=fgetc(fp);
        int p=c-'0';
        reverse(str,p);
        c=fgetc(fp);
        if(c==EOF)
        break;
        else
        c=fgetc(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Compile with -g and run it through a dubugger.

Comment: You might want to reconsider the `while(1)` and `break` statements. It's not very good style.

Comment: How big it the file? How much do you read into the array? And what happens if you get EOF before you expect it?

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  If the file contains a single line, your EOF detection will come across a newline, and restart the loop looking for new numbers and semicolons...but get EOF.  It won't stop, though, because you don't check each `fgetc()`.  The `memset(str, '0', 100)` should probably be `memset(str, '\0', sizeof(str));`, where the more important change is `'0'` to `'\0'`.

Comment: You can not detect EOF if you use `char c`. You have to use `int c`. With a char, the character with ascii code 255 and EOF are identical.

Comment: @tristopia: you're right there are problems with EOF detection.  The actual problem depends on whether `char` is signed or unsigned.  If it is signed, then there's a valid character (often ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS, 0xFF) that will be mistaken for EOF.  If `char` is unsigned, then the returned value will never match EOF.

Comment: @Jonathan yes, indeed. But you found his `segmentation fault` with the '0' initialisation of the buffer, it guarantees buffer oveflows in his reverse function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably other ways to do it, but this code works. You did a good job on the algorithm in `reverse()`. In the `reverse()` function, the only changes were formatting of the code and adding the more complete diagnostic printing.  The `main()` function was rewritten to read a line using `fgets()` and then parse that line.  If nothing else, doing that makes it easier to report erroneous input (though the code does not report properly on lines that do not contain a semicolon, for example, and the code assumes that the `k` items at a time is always a single digit, and it does not insist on single digits separated by commas, and ...).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void reverse(char str[], int p)
{
    int i, j, k, a, b;
    int len = strlen(str);
    printf("Input:  %d: %s (%d)\n", len, str, p);
    a = 0;
    b = p - 1;
    while (1)
    {
        i = a;
        j = b;
        while (j > i)
        {
          k = str[i];
          str[i] = str[j];
          str[j] = k;
          i++;
          j--;
        }
        a = a + p;
        b = b + p;
        if (b >= len)
            break;  
    }
    printf("Output: ");
    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        printf("%c, ", str[i]);
    if (i == len - 1)
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong number of arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File can't be openend:\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char line[100];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
    {
        printf("Read:   %s", line);
        fflush(0);
        char str[100];
        int k = 0;
        int i = 0;
        char c;
        while ((c = line[i++]) != '\0')
        {
            if (c == ';')
                break;
            else if (c == ',')
                continue;
            else
                str[k++] = c;
        }
        str[k] = '\0';
        printf("String: %s\n", str);
        if (c == ';')
        {
            c = line[i];
            int p = c - '0';
            reverse(str, p);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample input data

```
1,2,3,4,5;2
1,2,3,4,5,6,7;3
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;2
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;3
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;4
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;5
```

#### Sample output

```
Read:   1,2,3,4,5;2
String: 12345
Input:  5: 12345 (2)
Output: 2, 1, 4, 3, 5
Read:   1,2,3,4,5,6,7;3
String: 1234567
Input:  7: 1234567 (3)
Output: 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 7
Read:   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;2
String: 123456789
Input:  9: 123456789 (2)
Output: 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 9
Read:   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;3
String: 123456789
Input:  9: 123456789 (3)
Output: 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7
Read:   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;4
String: 123456789
Input:  9: 123456789 (4)
Output: 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9
Read:   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;5
String: 123456789
Input:  9: 123456789 (5)
Output: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

#### Debugging the original

If you have to debug the original code, then the diagnostic printing in `reverse()` that I added would help there.  In the `main()` code, you'd need to think about echoing each character as it arrives, and perhaps printing the `str` array.  You'd need to be careful there because you filled it with zeros.  You might use `printf("String: %.*s\n", k, str);` to limit the output to the first `k` characters of `str`.